# I think my ex-employer secretely kept me in their system as an employee

Tags: hiring-process, employer-relations

I used to work for a company as a General Manager, but gave my notice for a couple reasons. One reason was due to a medical issue and the other was their cult-like culture. This is a fairly large restaurant chain.

As of today, I've been separated from the company for 2 months. However, I received a letter in the mail stating that I have been on "non-medical leave of absence" for the last week that's expected to last for another 3 weeks. I think my regional manager has secretly kept me listed as "employed".

The way this company works is that when a new person is hired, the manager/trainer of that person can receive a bonus. I believe it's $5,000 for a new General Manager, if I'm remembering correctly. The catch is that the person has to work there for at least X number of months, which I didn't reach when I quit. In my opinion, it's likely that my manager has extended my employment to receive the bonus.

What issues could this raise for me? One that sticks out to me is that background checks might show I worked somewhere for a different amount of time that I actually did.

Comment: Have you been receiving paychecks from your old company for the past two months?  You should be if you are still in their system as an employee.

Comment: @sf02 That was exactly what I was thinking as well - the only issue I would see is on what to spend that voluntary paycheck on.. ;)

Comment: "Non-medical leave of absence" usually is non-paid even when the employee is salary. But OP stated earlier that she was hourly so didn't expect to get paychecks when not working anyways.

Answer (score 23):

> What issues could this raise for me?

You are right to be concerned, this could *cause you some pain down* the road for the exact reasons you spelled out in your question.

What I would do is *send an email and a certified letter* to the Corporate Office HQ where the HR head resides and **confirm your departure date**.  If you provided a letter when your resigned, provide a copy of that too ( or email ).

If you did not resign in writing, always *make sure you do* for cases just like this.

Comment: I would add a copy of the letter you received, and suggest that maybe some data somewhere was not fully updated. That gives them a lead to investigate what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you contact HR directly and check that the date you were terminated (finished) is that which you expect.

If they have changed the date by extending it, then you should be paid for that time :)

So, hopefully this should be clarified and sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I’m confused. When you left, did you just walk off or formally resign/quit w/2wks notice? Bc yes, like they said above, you’d still be getting checks you’d think. At least til your ‘leave’ expires. Apparently not paid leave I’m guessing. Hard to tell. If they’re shady as you say it may be a scam & if they don’t remove your name. I’d say I’m reporting you to Supv. or whoever. If they still carryon against you. I’d go to the press. Find an investigative reporter to do a story on it.

Comment: I gave a two weeks notice and worked it. I wouldn't receive any checks because I'm technically hourly, not salaried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference with last day work and termination date. If you provided notice, did you work your notice or did they pay you out. Also, you had a medical concern, based on the Medical concern it could make a protected class. Whenever I term employment I always verify my separation date with HR.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like you're right...mgr wanted that bonus so he found a sneaky way to keep you in the system. He did not know you would receive something in the mail. As suggested in previous posts, if you have proof of resignation in form of a letter, contact HR to advise them of the situation.  Even if you don't have proof, call them anyway.  You may be doing them a big favor...he's not honest and who knows what else he could do behind their backs? Your decision...is the mgr a crook or a man in desperate times....